# HTML/CSS - how to align boxes / divs

Tags: html, css

I hope you can help me, it is somewhat an issue for me. I have 4 divs, and each one contains an image and a little text. I want to align them so they look like this 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be a little more specific, i.e. what your current html and css is and and example link.

A simple solution is to just float all 4 divs, giving them fixed width's and height's, clear the left float on the third div so that the final two divs drop down to the second line.

You don't even have to clear the third div if you just set a 50% width on the divs but that's dependent on if you are using fixed width's and height's, i.e responsive sites shunn fixed width's.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really being clear.

In the styling set 'float:left' and 'width:50%;' for each div.

Comment: and also wrap your content in another element, so you can have that white margins

Comment: Exactly, that would be helpful as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put them in wrapper, here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/5Sz75/)**</kbd>

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"><img src="/" alt="Image"><span>Text 1</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="/" alt="Image"><span>Text 2</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="/" alt="Image"><span>Text 3</span></div>
  <div class="box"><img src="/" alt="Image"><span>Text 4</span></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.wrapper {
  width: 220px;
}
.box {
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.box img {
  width: 100%;
}
.box span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<ul>
    <li>first box</li>
    <li>second box</li>
    <li>third box</li>
    <li>fouth box</li>
<ul>
```

css:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    widht: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    padding: 20px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(2n) {
   float: right;
}
```